# How does one correctly set the target page of indexed search results in typo3?

Tags: search, typo3, typoscript

I am working with typo3 4.7 and trying to redirect the search results of the indexed search plugin to a page in my site and managed to stumble upon the constants editor where I've managed to use it to guide me in setting up the object. Below is the current typoscript of the object in my root template (mapped into a TV template):

```
# --- SEARCHBOX OBJECT ---------------------------------- 
lib.searchbox < plugin.tx_indexedsearch
lib.searchbox{
#Disable the advanced search link
show.advancedSearchLink = 0
show.rules = 0
show.alwaysShowPageLinks = 1

#pid of root page is 1 and pid of the search result page is 9
search.rootPidList = 1
search.targetPid = 1
view.defaultPid = 9
result_link_target = 9
}
```

Thus far I have been unsuccessful in my attempts and all results are displayed in the page in where the search was performed. I would also like to know if it is possible to modify the displayed search box so that only the search field is displayed.
Thanks for your time.

Edit: I have installed and I'm trying out solr, if anyone has any experience with it pls feel free to help resolve this issue. My two problems with solr so far is that whilst search does re-direct to the right page, (1) the search box is way too big so I need to be able to modify the display of this box (to remove the button and reduce the size) (2) it spouts som e messages about search rules and returns nothing so far.

Edit 2: Seems solr is the way forward. I have managed to get everything I want done except the result output. I lost a few days (5) before realising that the tomcat container was bound to an ipv6 protocol interface. Resolving that [(see here for those who may stumble upon the same problem for how to resolve this)](https://serverfault.com/questions/390840/how-does-one-get-tomcat-to-bind-to-ipv4-address) has meant I can now remotely admin the solr server for more information. The pages are being indexed (Not regularly as specified in the scheduler) but I still get no results on the result page, and devlog only returns warning about there not being typo3 search markers despite my TV templates being peppered with them. I can only guess that maybe I'm to mark the results page with some type of marker to get the results to show at this point.

Comment: Solr is a good choice. The fact that your question remained unsolved until today speaks for the inflexibility of indexed_search. Another good option is ke_search, but solr is more powerful.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
plugin.tx_indexedsearch {
   search {
    targetPid >
    targetPid = 123
   }
}
```

Reference: http://lists.typo3.org/pipermail/typo3-team-core/2010-March/036269.html

Experience: works even in TYPO3 version 6.x.

Default setting for plugin.tx_indexedsearch.search.targetPid is:

```
plugin.tx_indexedsearch {
   search {
    # TSFE:id is always the current page
    targetPid.data = TSFE:id
   }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I have never used the indexedsearch plugin as the searchbox on all of my pages.

Normally, I do this

- Create a page with the indexed_search plugin as its content, this is
  where all search requests are answered
- Use macina_searchbox to
  display a search box as part of the template

To elaborate:

Install macina_searchbox, and use this Typoscript to configure it

```
plugin.tx_macinasearchbox_pi1 {
    pidSearchpage = {PID_OF_SEARCH_RESULT_PAGE}
    templateFile = {PATH_TO_TEMPLATE_FILE_FOR_SEARCH_BOX}
}
```

Then, include macina_searchbox like so

```
lib.searchbox <  plugin.tx_macinasearchbox_pi1
```

The search result page just needs the indexed_search plugin where you want the results to be displayed.

Comment: The problem isn't displaying the search box, but how to modify it's view (i.e. get rid of the button and search box labels) and critically, how to redirect the query results to another page.

Comment: I understand you correctly that displaying the results is not the issue, but that you want to have a search box on every page (as part of the template)? Both of these things (custom search box template and redirect to a different result page) are exactly what macina_searchbox does (it does nothing else).

Comment: We have struggled with this plugin for a few hours now and so far no success. It even does more damage to our TV template than the solr plugin. The only problem we have now is that, although it takes us to the right page (just like solr), it doesn't display any results.

Comment: you need the indexed_search plugin on the page it redirects you to. macina_searchbox does not actually do the search, it just redirects search querys to the correct page.

Comment: We tried all of this before I posted as I had to go join the other dev to try and resolve this. It was decided after asking for help on the IRC to abandon macina for solr as of 3 days ago. Especially since it will be far more useful for our other sites in the long run.

Answer (score 0):

I would just create a search box, copy the HTML-Code, adjust action-url and HTML-Code and output it. IMHO there is no need, to render it via Plugin, if you just need an search-input field and an button. But do not forget the hidden fields!

Comment: I need it mapped in templavoila so that should it be required to move it to another part of the page then this would be easy. Also it is a requirement that the search box (without button or a label) be present on every page.